# Copy HTML/rich text using navigator.clipboard

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, copy-paste, navigator

Based on [Clipboard Write API specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write#specifications) I could copy to clipboard like below:

```
    const type = "text/plain";
    const text = "test plain";
    const blob = new Blob([text], { type });
    const data = [new ClipboardItem({ [type]: blob })];

    navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
        () => {alert('success plain copy')},
        () => {}
    );
```

I tried that and that worked. But I tried to change the type to HTML or rich text like below:

```
    const type = "text/html"
    const text = "<b>text html</b>";
    const blob = new Blob([text], { type });
    const data = [new ClipboardItem({ [type]: blob })];

    navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
        () => {alert('success html copy')},
        () => {}
    );
```

And it doesn't work. The success alert is shown up, but the HTML text is not copied.

I have conducted online research and based on my findings, my code appears to be correct. However, it is puzzling why it is not functioning as intended.

By the way, actually I want to create a SO snippet, but the permission is blocked, so if others want to try my codes, you check on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtupemyx/3/)

Comment: just copy the html under `text/plain` type. not as `text/html`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky I need to copy html text or rich text, not plain text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an [article](https://www.nikouusitalo.com/blog/why-isnt-clipboard-write-copying-my-richtext-html/) that solved the problem.

I just realized, if I need to add both `text/plain` and `text/html` to `ClipboardItem` object. Maybe `text/plain` is required to allow system paste as plain (cmd/ctrl+shift+v).

Here is the correct code:

```
const originalText = "Original Text"
const boldText = "<b>"+originalText+"</b>";
const blobHtml = new Blob([boldText], { type: "text/html" });
const blobText = new Blob([originalText], { type: "text/plain" });
const data = [new ClipboardItem({
    ["text/plain"]: blobText,
    ["text/html"]: blobHtml,
})];

navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
    () => {alert('success html copy')},
    () => {}
);
```

You can check the worked demo on
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtupemyx/5/)